# Is it safe to delete WCFDiagnosticsExample.svclog

Tags: c#, asp.net, trace

I was perusing our server looking for overly large files, and I came across one called "WCFDiagnosticsExample.svclog", and it is currently around 48GB. From the research I've done, this is larger than the file should get. I have no idea who set it up, but it's there. Can I safely delete it, or is there some sort of procedure I need to do first?

Comment: No procedure. If you dont need it then just press shift + del on it so that it wont come back.

Comment: eh, well, shift + delete will bypass the recycling bin when deleting the file. If Visual Studio or another program wants to make it again it can.